# settings.android.largeHeap in corona sdk and screen orientation

Tags: android, lua, orientation, coronasdk

my **build.settings** file is

```
    settings = {
      orientation =
      {
        default = "landscapeRight",
        supported =
        {
        "landscapeLeft", "landscapeRight"
        }
     }
   }
```

all work fine
but when I change the **build.settings** file to

```
   settings = {
    android =
    {       
        largeHeap = true    
    }
    orientation =
    {
        default = "landscapeRight",
        supported =
        {
        "landscapeLeft", "landscapeRight"
        }
    }
}
```

orientation of the device is set to **"portrait"**, "NOT landscapeRight".

I need to have "landscapeRight" orientation and android setting "settings.android.largeHeap = true" together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the comma after android ={}. It should be like this:

```
android = {
  largeHeap = true
},
```